# How can I write a more complex search in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to return a list of dates within 30 days of a given day. For example, I want to be able to input todays date and I want excel to search a separate table, with multiple columns of dates. If it finds one within 30 days of today, AND the value of the cell to the left of the date reads "no", then I want it to return the date, the row, and the column.

My initial thought is to define the range of the table and loop through the cells. Then add an if statement that compares each cell with today's date. If they're within 30 days, it will check the value to the left with another if statement. If the value to the left reads no, then it will assign variable = cell value, row number, column number.

In theory, this will leave me with a list of variables that are my matches. Then, all I have to do it report the list of variables in a cell. My vba skills are basic so I need help with the actual diction.

***Update
At this point I'm just trying to get a working loop:

```vb
Sub GenerateReport()
    'must have selection to work
    
    'Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim TD() As Variant
    ReDim TD(Selection.Cells.Count)
    
    i = 1
    
    For Each rng In Selection
    
    If IsDate(Cell.Value) Then
        If Abs(CDate(Cell.Value) - SearchDate) <= 30 And LCase(Cell.Offset(0, -1).Value) = "no" Then
        TD(i) = Cell.Value
        Else
        TD(i) = 0
        i = i + 1
    End If
    End If
    Next
    
End Sub
```

I would expect to get a list of 1s and 0s from this, but I can't get it to run.

Comment: Sounds like you have the basic steps worked out, so why not make a start: create the loop and add some logic.  If you run into a specific problem, update your post with the code you're working with.

Comment: Here are some pieces to get you started: A loop - `For Each Cell In MyRange.Cells` - The test - `If IsDate(Cell.Value) Then If Abs(CDate(Cell.Value) - SearchDate) <= 30 And LCase(Cell.Offset(0,-1).Value) = "no" Then ` - And the data to return - Date:`Cell.Value`, Row:`Cell.Row`, Column:`Cell.Column`

Comment: `For Each Rng in Selection` will successfully loop through each cell in a user selected range. `GoTo SearchForDate` will exit the loop and restart it from the first cell, creating an infinite loop on the first cell where the If Statement is false.

Comment: @Toddleson     This is my best shot using your guidance: Sub ReportDates()
Dim x As Date
For Each Cell In MyRange.Cells

If IsDate(Cell.Value) Then
    If Abs(CDate(Cell.Value) - SearchDate) <= 30 And LCase(Cell.Offset(0, -1).Value) = "no" Then
    x = Cell.Value
    Else
    x = 0
End If
End If
Next

End Sub

Comment: @Toddleson I took out the GoTo part and I am getting a Type mismatch error now

Comment: Hi, try this and let us know...
Sub GenerateReport()
'must have selection to work

'Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim TD As Variant ' I would rather use: TD(1000) as long

i = 1

For Each rng In Selection

    If rng.Value2 = "12/20/2021" Then
        TD(i) = 1
    Else
        TD(i) = 0
    End If
    i = i + 1

Next

End Sub

Comment: `TD` is declared as a variant value, you will get Type Mismatch error because you're trying to use it as an array. if you want `TD` as an array, [declare](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/declaring-arrays) it like `Dim TD() as Variant`. But you need to also declare its size in that line or in a following line like `Redim TD(Selection.Cells.Count)`.

Comment: @toddleson I made some edits to the post above. I think I'm getting closer but now I'm getting an object error on the first if line.  Any suggestions?

Comment: `If IsDate(Cell.Value) Then` should be `If IsDate(rng.Value) Then` and also for other spots where you've used `Cell`

Answer (score 3):

You could do something along these lines:

```vb
Sub GenerateReportFromSelection()
    
    Dim c As Range, col As New Collection, v
    
    For Each c In Selection.Cells
        If c.Column > 1 Then    'make sure you can offset one col to left...
            v = c.value         'read the value once
            If IsDate(v) Then
                If Abs(CDate(v) - Date) <= 30 And _
                   LCase(c.Offset(0, -1).value) = "no" Then
                    
                    col.Add c   'add cell to collection
                End If          '30 days + no
            End If              'is a date
        End If                  'col>1
    Next
    
    'review the hits
    Debug.Print "---Matches---"
    For Each c In col
        Debug.Print c.value, c.Row, c.Column
    Next c
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking. And importantly, you check for `IsDate` in a seperate statement before attempting `CDate`, which prevents errors in runtime from being unable to convert values.

Comment: You are my hero, thanks to you both!